Issue with FFmpegKit in React Native: "Cannot read property 'ffmpegSession' of null"
I am new to React Native and Expo, and I’m trying to upload a video using expo-image-picker, then pass its URI to FFmpegKit (ffmpeg-kit-react-native) to extract frames from the video.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:

I’m using expo-image-picker to upload the video and retrieve its URI.
I use FileSystem.documentDirectory to get the local file path from the URI and then pass this path to the FFmpegKit command.

However, I’m encountering the following error:
Cannot read property 'ffmpegSession' of null
I’ve tried calling FFmpegKitConfig.init() before executing the command, but the result is still the same.
Can someone help me understand what I might be doing wrong? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

